# Julia read from text file and skip after comment

Tags: text, julia

I am reading data from a text file which has the below format
256     # nx, ny
I want to assign a value 256 to a variable and skip the text after # (comment character in Julia). How can I do that?
Thank upi

Comment: Something along the lines of `parse(Int, split("256 # nx, ny", "#")[1])`? Error handling would need to be added of course.

Comment: I used nx = parse(Int,split(readline(file_input), "#")). The first line of .txt file is 256  # nx, ny. I got MethodError.

Comment: You have forgotten to add `[1]`, so it should be `nx = parse(Int,split(readline(file_input), "#")[1])`.